# how to get the current block author?

Tags: pallet, frame, consensus, aura, frame-system

I am creating a new pallet, i have a simple task, get the current block author, i want to check whether I am the current one that is proposing the block or not by comparing the current block author with my id.

Unfortunately i have been looking and asking everywhere but there is no clear straightforward way of doing it in aura. it would be great if someone show me a step by step guide on how to solve this and how to properly think about solving such problems.

Comment: The current block author for the parachain or for the relay chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by implementing the [`pallet_authorship::EventHandler`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_authorship/trait.EventHandler.html). `pallet-collator-selection` [does exactly this](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/220bc559f064d38485d5a21e2ba91a8a237e9d16/pallets/collator-selection/src/lib.rs#L472-L498), which is a pretty straightforward example.

Then, in the top level runtime, any pallet who's interested in receiving these events about block authorship has to be passed to the authorship pallet:

```rust
// in your pallet
impl<T: Config> pallet_authorship::EventHandler for Pallet<T> {..}

// in `runtime/lib.rs`
impl pallet_authorship::Config {
  type EventHandler: (PalletA, PalletB, ...)
  ..
}
```

[Example](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/220bc559f064d38485d5a21e2ba91a8a237e9d16/parachains/runtimes/collectives/collectives-polkadot/src/lib.rs#L189-L194).

Comment: will it work in pow substrate chain?