# Is it possible to fetch the validator's public address who participate during the grandpa finality of the current block?[updated]

Tags: pallet, validator, block, address

I'm working on a chain where I need to gather the validator's public address who participates in the grandpa finality process and validate the current block.

For ex:
let's say we have 10 validators which is going to participate in grandpa finality of the current block and out of 10 validators, 6 validators validate and approve the current block during grandpa finality process. So I need the public address of these 6 validators.

Thanks

Comment: Is this not the same as you asked last week https://substrate.stackexchange.com/q/10934/116 Please elaborate more how this is a different question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the validators list?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/how-to-get-the-validators-list)

Comment: Who is the validator who "approved" the current block? Do you mean the block author? in this case: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/how-to-get-the-current-block-author/5395

Comment: @kianenigma The validator who validate the current block

Comment: @Simson this question(https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/how-to-get-the-validators-list) does not have the answer what I'm expecting

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary edit the question to tell us that, and give us a bit more context.

Comment: @Simson update the question, please let me know if you find something not understandable.

Comment: I have to ask the same. What do you mean by "validated the current block"? The only meaning of "validate" I know is the author, but I am not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: @kianenigma sorry about that, let's say we have 10 validators which is going to participate in grandpa finality of the current block and out of 10 validators, 6 validators validate and approve the current block during grandpa finality process. So I need the public address of these 6 validators.

Comment: I don't think that information is available on-chain.